# Override CollectionTable in ElementCollection of MappedSuperClass

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I have an abstract base class (*@MappedSuperclass*) with an embedded *@ElementCollection*. I have multiple concrete extensions of this class and they work fine. I get a table per extension class, which is what I'm looking for. The problem is in the naming of the table that is created for the *ElementCollection* in some of the classes. I'm using Oracle which has a relatively small limit for the table names. I have control over the table names associated with the top level classes, but I don't seem to have control over the name of the table created for the *@ElementCollection*. It is always named *TopLevelClassName_ElementCollectionName*. It uses the class name directly rather than the table name specified by the owner class, and I can't find a way to override it in any way.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try to add this annotation `@CollectionTable(name="YOURTABLE")` alongside with the `@ElementCollection` with the proper table name. If it works I will add as an answer.

Comment: Already tried. It will give the *same* fixed table name to the child table for *all* concrete classes.

Comment: That's odd... Maybe AttributeOverride then. See it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html

Comment: Again, not quite. My ElementCollection is in the abstract class and I'm trying to set the table name on a per-concrete basis, not override the element names. I'm actually not sure it's possible and may end up having to shorten/uglify the names of my classes so that they fit within Oracle's length constraints.

Comment: @Nerdfest can you add your mappings?

Comment: I'll try to remember tomorrow. Really, I'm against the whole "one table per class" thing for these values anyway as it's repetitive, tedious, and requires each table, dao, service, etc, to be cut and pasted. It's very error prone. Still, I hate leaving a problem unsolved.

Comment: Same problem here, I can't make it work. If the superclass has no `@CollectionTable`, I can override using `@AssociationOverride`. But if the superclass has `@CollectionTable`, I can't override it...